# Ошибка в коде С2065

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double y, x, a, b, e, f, p1, p2, p3, l1, f1, p1p, l1l;
    e = 2.71;
    cin >> a >> x >> y >> b;

    while (x * y > 0)
    {
        f + pow(e, x * y + a);
        cout << "Ответ: 1";
        break;
    }
    while (x * y == 0)
    {
        f = b - min(x + y, y * b);
        cout << f;
    }
    while (x * y < 0)
    {
        p1p = y + x;

        p1 = pow(p1p, 2);
        l1l = 1 + p1;
        l1 = log(l1l);
        f1 = fabs(l1);

        p2 = pow(x, 2);
        p3 = pow(e, y);
        
        max(p2, p3, sqrt(f1));
        cout << "Ответ: 3";
    }
}
```

показывает ошибку " 'C2064'    Результатом вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 2 аргументов"
Подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить этот недуг?
[image: Вот такие ошибочки]

Comment: а вот эта строка что делает? `f + pow(e, x * y + a);`

Comment: Это что и зачем?   `max(p2, p3, sqrt(f1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас не определена функция `max` для произвольного числа аргументов. Это не проблема, так как

```
max(a,b,c,d,...)
```

это то же самое, что

```
max(a,max(b,max(c,...)))
```

Ну то есть брать максимумы у пар, а потом сравнивать их между собой.

Но это ерунда! у вас весь код просто кричит о неверности, хотя и выдаются компилятором только предупреждения (и то не для всех ошибок).

`main()` возвращает `int`, не `void`!

```
f + pow(e, x * y + a);
```

И что это значит? Вы вычисляете что-то, и плевать на него — это ненужное значение? Вы его в принципе не используете?

Да и вычислять `e` в степени что-то надо уж никак не через `pow` для значения 2.71 (ужасно...) — есть нормальная стандартная функция `exp()` специально для этого.

Да и само максимальное значение, о котором вы спрашиваете, вы тоже нигде не используете. Может, надо просто выбросить эту строчку?

Ваши циклы `while` бесконечные, так как условие у них никогда не изменяется!

Учтите: **компилируется — не значит работает**!